# React with Typescript | Functional component | Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I've set up a project that uses TypeScript with React. So I went on to create a Layout component which uses the children prop. This is my current code:

```
import React from 'react';

type LayoutProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const Layout: React.FC<LayoutProps> = ({children}) => (
    <>
        {children}
    </>
)

export default Layout;
```

For some reason I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any>'.
```

[image]

I've searched around a bit and am still unsure as to why I would be getting this error. I should also mention this is a NextJS project. When NextJS tries to compile the code I get this error:
[image]

Comment: This code does not produce any errors on its own. How are you using the Layout component? Show the actual code that passes props to it.

Comment: I haven't actually used it yet. So nowhere.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that this is a NextJS project.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgBkVqIBXGABRzAGc4BeOAG9ycMXDQALYABsAJkQB2ALkTEYAOmToYAOQhyk5AL6U0ERT3hMW7VdowaAYgGEAPDbaduPAHwC4AAohKVkFJEVjAEoBf0DRcTdfBPFxEOl5JVNUtwB6ZKjKJAAPSFg4Q0wUVhlrZi8KIA). I can tell you from experience though that the Typescript compiler is confusing your JSX tag with a generic type parameter for a function call.

Comment: Try .tsx, not .ts

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue seemed to be Typescript not understanding that this was JSX. As [Robert Kawecki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871026/react-with-typescript-functional-component-type-boolean-is-not-assignable?noredirect=1#comment118207091_66871026) suggested, changing from a .ts to .tsx file fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

When you're using the `React.FC` type, you don't have to specify the `children` prop. It's automatically added to props. So in your case, you could simply do:

```
import React from 'react';

// You don't have to provide a type argument to `React.FC`
const Layout: React.FC = ({children}) => (
    <>
        {children}
    </>
)

export default Layout;
```

For clarity, here's the definition of the `FunctionComponent` interface:

```js
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

Comment: I realize this, I choose to include it. As to the error, it doesn't make a difference - still get it. I edit the post to also mention that this is a NextJS project, if that makes any difference.  When NextJS tries to compile the code I get a syntax error: Type parameter list cannot be empty.